# Is it ok to use Gevent and threading together?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, gevent

For example - I have some class that internally uses Gevent for concurrency, and it takes a callback, what if user of my class will use Python `threading` or `multiprocessing` modules? Will this lead the program to disaster?

### UPDATE

Some more details:
My class is a custom protocol implementation, so it involves lots of reading/writing with sockets. Protocol includes such feature as option to send multiple requests (within single TCP connection) in order to load multiple cores on a server, and then wait for responses. That's why I need concurrency. This class is a library which will be part of a large project, and it can be used in every possible crazy way. I'm also new to Gevent and I barely aware about monkey-patching feature.

Comment: How are you actually using `gevent`? Are you monkey patching anything?

Comment: I had the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199242/can-one-small-portion-of-an-app-use-gevent-or-does-the-whole-app-have-to-switch

I discovered the answer is no.

Comment: @dano Look at the update plz.

Comment: @stephenbez To clarify - "no" means - "Gevent breaks things, do not use it with other concurrency stuff"? Have found any other libraries for that use case?

Comment: @GillBates There is a library called [`gipc`](http://gehrcke.de/gipc/) that's specifically designed to make it possible to use `multiprocessing` in the context of `gevent`. It states: *"...canonical usage of Python’s `multiprocessing` module within a `gevent`-powered application may raise various problems and most likely breaks the application in many ways."* That page also goes into some specific issues that `multiprocessing` can cause when mixed with `gevent`.

Comment: @GillBates To clarify, it is not ok to use gevent and threading/multiprocessing together as it will cause problems.  I don't know any other libraries for this use case.

Comment: As far as I understand you only have issues if you use gevent monkey patching or mixing gevent and threading code. As long as your gevent code is separate and not sharing anything like queues with the rest and you don't do monkey patching you are fine.

Comment: Isn't the whole purpose of the gevent monkeypatch code to make modules like threading and requests play nice witht the gevent event loop? _IF_ you import and patch in the proper order.